# How to send multiple json documents into marklogic database through post request in REST api using java?

Tags: java, rest, marklogic

In PUT request we can send a single document using string or any stream by placing it in http entity.
But how can we send a post request for inserting multiple documents into **marklogic** database through REST api?

Comment: Are you using the marklogic java client? https://developer.marklogic.com/products/java

Comment: actually i am using java...but need to implement by rest-api. Rest api documents is also present but not properly mentioned in them

Comment: Did you check the documentation for POST:/v1/documents ? The example at the bottom of the site shows how to create multiple documents in a single request: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/documents. Also this chapter might be helpful: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#chapter

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned you're using the ML Java client, in which case you can use a [`DocumentWriteSet`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentWriteSet.html) - see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/bulk#id_40578

Comment: But we can't send that using rest-api...so can u tell using rest-api

Comment: It's using the REST API under the hood - specifically the /v1/documents endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check out XQRS, it automatically casts XML, JSON and RDF into their respective XQuery types too, e.g. document-node(element()), document-node(object-node()) and sem:triple* etc

See

https://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs/docs/post-put-body#multipart-types

Answer (score 0):

this repo https://github.com/DALDEI/mlperf.git  has multiple examples of loading json documents singular and in bulk using a variety of techniques and apis